# Cordova/Phonegap - WP8 - Problemas ao carregar imagens externas(URL)

Tags: apache-cordova, imagem, windows-phone-8-1

Estou tendo problemas com o *Cordova/Phonegap* com WP8.

Se vocês tentarem criar uma página e carregar uma imagem da internet (`<img>` com URL) o WP8 não apresenta a imagem, somente quando a imagem está na pasta `/www`. Preciso saber o que fazer para resolver isso porque nas plataformas iOS e Android o carregamento ocorre normalmente.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente, para você ter acesso a imagens externas através da tag **img** certifique se, que colocou

```
<access origin="*" />
```

no arquivo **config.xml**

Já no caso de img na pasta local, no Android e iOS ele reconhece, as pastas normalmente sem a necessidade de colocar o caminho desde a raiz www, mas em alguns casos como com arquivos de audio ele precisa colocar o caminho completo.

Ex.

> '/android_asset/www/audio/cd1/intro.mp3'